# Balanced Binary Search Tree Keys

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I'm trying to figure out how to key the elements of binary search tree which stores "line segments". The computational geometry book I'm reading says

> In more detail, we store the segments intersecting the sweep line ordered in the leaves of a balanced binary search tree T. The left-to-right order of the segments along the sweep line corresponds to the left-to-right order of the leaves in T

Assuming the key is the x/y value of the event point (here, either A or B) how will the status structure hold the correct order of line segments given the following situation (the dashed line is the sweep line).

[image]

B clearly hits the sweep line before A, and yet if the segment for B is added by it x/y value it will be after A in the status line.

So it seems to me the keys for the segments of the status line cannot be static values like the x/y value of a point – but the book is pretty quiet on how the tree is constructed in that regard. I've seen some examples given the keys as the tuple of (m,b) where `m` is the lines gradient and `b` is the y-intercept, but I'm less clear on how that works.

Comment: I think the key is the intersection point (i.e. x if the sweep line is horizontal, y if it's vertical).

Comment: There isn't a static ordering. Every time the sweep line hits an intersection of two line segments, those line segments exchange places in the search tree.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, these two segments don't intersect – more than that, `B` isn't in the status structure yet.

Comment: I guess my question is – What keying of the structure would allow this particular system of segments to be correctly stored as the ordering `B A` when `B` is added to the status structure. It can't be `x,y` of the point from the queue (aka the start point of the segment) because that would give the ordering `A B` for the above segments as the `x,y` of `A` is less than the `x,y` of `B`.

Comment: Is the key a description of the line? Therefore in the case above, when we search for where to put `B` when adding it to the status structure we get the first node `A` (the only node in this case), plug the `y` value of the sweep line into the description for `A` to get a specific point on `A`, then compare that to our point `B` – `B` will either lay to the left of right of `A`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store segments in the same order as they intersect sweep line at the current moment. It's possible with binary search tree because of its nature: left nodes contain lower keys, right nodes - greater keys.

Due to the dynamic nature of the structure the key also will be dynamic. Each time you add a segment into the BST (binary search tree) you need to compare the key, which will be X component of the intersection point on sweep line, at its Y coordinate.

At the moment of intersection of the sweep line with B segment, or B segments start point, A segment has been already added to the BST at A segments start point. So following the rules of BST item insertion you need to check the key of B segment, which is X coordinate at Y, if it's greater or lower than the keys of items of the BST. It's obvious that the X coordinate at Y for B is less than the X coordinate at Y of A, so the B segment will be added to the left node of the BST

```
      A
    /   \
   B     null
  / \
null null
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

In the end I implemented each node as a tuple of the values that would describe a line for any given x value e.g [ m, c ] for `y = mx + c`. Storing the data as points makes it harder to search and compare values

Comment: Nice solution. When I was implementing it I was using general form of the line instead of slope intercept. Slope intercept does not cover vertical lines, so how have you solved that? Have you handled that special case?